# Error when trying to install stellar-sdk from npm, "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libe ay32.lib'"

Tags: javascript-sdk, stellar-sdk, cli

Anyone know what this means or how to fix it?

I ran the command `npm install --save stellar-sdk`
and got this

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libe
ay32.lib' [D:\Stellar\node_modules\ed25519\build\ed25519.vcxp
roj]
```

Any help/explanation is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: IF anyone else encountered this issue, you can just ignore it and it wtill works fine.

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL installed?

Comment: I was searching for an answer to this and tried. I downloaded 3 different Open SSL versions from [here](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/) and put them in the path specified but they only have a `libeay32.dll` and not a `libeay32.lib` . I also tried just changing the .dll to a .lib but still got an error.

Comment: It's not a critical error, just ignore it. `ed25519` package offers binaries for the fast ED25519 signing, but it's an optional dependency. Bundled crypto-js version works just fine.

Comment: I get that error too.. like what @OrbitLens said, you can ignore it and the sdk will work fine.